# Issues with MySQL query - INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'll post the code below. Beneath the code is where I will pose my question.

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['password']))  
{  

$server=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['server']);
$teamname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['teamname']);
$creator=$_SESSION['username'];
$verify = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['verify']);
$date = date("F j, Y, g:i a");

if (!empty($teamname)) {
//  if ($verify == "wookie" ||
//  $verify == "Wookie" ||
//  $verify == "WOOKIE") 
//  {
        $sql="INSERT INTO rated_teams (server, name, creator, created, players, win, loss)
                            VALUES ('$server', '$teamname', '$creator','$date', '', '', '')";

        if (mysql_query($sql,$con))
          {
            echo "<p>Added ". $teamname . " on " . $server . " by " . $creator . " on " . $date ." <br /><a href='myprofile.php'>Return to Profile</a></p>";
          }
         else
          {
            echo $sql . "<br />";
            echo "<br /><h1>Error</h1>";  
            echo "<p><a href='myprofile.php'>Sorry, your team registration has failed. Please go back and try again.</a></p>
            <br />" . $teamname . " on " . $server . " by " . $creator . " on " . $date;
          }
    //} else { echo "That isn't how you spell Wookie!"; }
} else { echo "Team Name is empty, <a href='myprofile.php'>go back and give yourself a Team Name</a>"; }
} else { echo "You must be <a href='login.php'>logged in</a>!"; }
```

This issue is that the line "if (mysql_query($sql,$con))" goes directly to the ELSE. I'm assuming the problem lies with my $sql but I can't pinpoint where it is. Another pair of eyes would really help. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: you can print $sql like this `echo $sql;` then take the query and test it with PHPMyAdmin

Comment: Why don't you add error handling to your query call? You can capture the MySQL error which should give you insight into the issue.

Comment: Perhaps your data has an apostrophe somewhere which is making the SQL invalid?  You should really use parameterized queries.

Comment: Check the contents of `mysql_error()`.

Comment: `mysql` is deprecated. You should be using `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: Always log the errors (or display them while the site is in development). It will make your life much easier. As others have said - echo the content of the string and see if it runs on its own. Other thing that pops in my mind - make sure the SQL connection is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trace errors with `mysql_query()` , you should use `mysql_error()`. Here's an example, inspired of one of the [PHP `mysql_error()` doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO rated_teams (server, name, creator, created, players, win, loss)
                        VALUES ('$server', '$teamname', '$creator','$date', '', '', '')";

    mysql_query($sql,$con);
     if (mysql_errno()) {
         $error = "MySQL error ".mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."\n<br>When executing:<br>\n$sql\n<br>";

        // Your stuff
        echo $sql . "<br />";
        echo "<br /><h1>Error</h1>";  
        echo "<p><a href='myprofile.php'>Sorry, your team registration has failed. Please go back and try again.</a></p>
        <br />" . $teamname . " on " . $server . " by " . $creator . " on " . $date;
      }
     else {
           echo "<p>Added ". $teamname . " on " . $server . " by " . $creator . " on " . $date ." <br /><a href='myprofile.php'>Return to Profile</a></p>"; 
      }
```

Also, you should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), since `mysql_*` are deprecated since PHP 5.x

Comment: @Akam Thanks! i forgot to add auto_increment to my primary key. DERP.